# Is this sum equal to 1?

Tags: probability, summation

Is this function $P:\mathbb{N}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$
P(i)=\frac{1}{m^n}((m-i+1)^n-(m-i)^n), \quad  i\in\mathbb{N}
$$

a probability over natural numbers?

I was trying to calculate if

$$
1=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{m^n}((m-i+1)^n-(m-i)^n)
$$

Comment: Is $m$ a positive integer?

Comment: Try writing out the full sum for some simple cases ($m=1,2,3$) and see if you can spot a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

The sum is telescoping
$$  \frac 1 {m^n} \sum_{i=1}^m \left[ (m-i+1)^n - (m-i)^n    \right] = \frac 1 {m^n} \left[ m^n - (m-1)^n + (m-1)^n - (m-2)^n + ... - 1^n + 1^n - 0   \right] = \frac 1 {m^n} m^n =1 $$